# How to set other cookie as authentication cookie?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, identity

I'm developing a custom ASP.NET Identity 2.0 implementation. By default, I'm logged in when I set the .AspNet.ApplicationCookie. I want to offer multiple ways to log in, and in my custom `AuthorizeAttribute` I want to check what method was used to log in. For example: impersonation, temporary password change token, google authenticator, etc.

My idea was that I can do this by making different authentication middlewares that set different cookies, e.g.:

- .AspNet.Impersonated
- .AspNet.Authenticator
- Etc.

The problem is: when I set a cookie other than .AspNet.ApplicationCookie, it's not recognized as an authentication cookie, meaning that it will be set, but it won't result in a logged in status.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: when you login user, add a custom claim with data about auth type to the indentity you authenticate with.